# How do you focus on new windows with selenium ide?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am trying to use selenium ide to duplicate an action. The action is clicking on a link that open a new window. How do you make selenium ide focus on the new window instead of the other one? It has not been working for me.

Comment: check out this link, i also posted in below, i get the feeling selectWindow is very broken: http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-703

Answer (score 8):

**Select Window**

For this you will need to use the `selectWindow | windowName` command.

To go back to the main window from the other window then do `selectWindow | null`

> ```
> Arguments:
>
>     * windowID - the JavaScript window ID of the window to select
>
> Selects a popup window using a window locator; once a popup window
> ```
>
> has been selected, all commands go to
>   that window. To select the main window
>   again, use null as the target.
>
> ```
> Window locators provide different ways of specifying the window object:
> ```
>
> by title, by internal JavaScript
>   "name," or by JavaScript variable.
>
> ```
>     * title=My Special Window: Finds the window using the text that
> ```
>
> appears in the title bar. Be careful;
>   two windows can share the same title.
>   If that happens, this locator will
>   just pick one.
>           * name=myWindow: Finds the window using its internal JavaScript
>   "name" property. This is the second
>   parameter "windowName" passed to the
>   JavaScript method window.open(url,
>   windowName, windowFeatures,
>   replaceFlag) (which Selenium
>   intercepts).
>           * var=variableName: Some pop-up windows are unnamed
>   (anonymous), but are associated with a
>   JavaScript variable name in the
>   current application window, e.g.
>   "window.foo = window.open(url);". In
>   those cases, you can open the window
>   using "var=foo".
>
> ```
> If no window locator prefix is provided, we'll try to guess what you
> ```
>
> mean like this:
>
> ```
> 1.) if windowID is null, (or the string "null") then it is assumed the
> ```
>
> user is referring to the original
>   window instantiated by the browser).
>
> ```
> 2.) if the value of the "windowID" parameter is a JavaScript variable
> ```
>
> name in the current application
>   window, then it is assumed that this
>   variable contains the return value
>   from a call to the JavaScript
>   window.open() method.
>
> ```
> 3.) Otherwise, selenium looks in a hash it maintains that maps string
> ```
>
> names to window "names".
>
> ```
> 4.) If that fails, we'll try looping over all of the known windows
> ```
>
> to try to find the appropriate
>   "title". Since "title" is not
>   necessarily unique, this may have
>   unexpected behavior.
>
> ```
> If you're having trouble figuring out the name of a window that you want
> ```
>
> to manipulate, look at the Selenium
>   log messages which identify the names
>   of windows created via window.open
>   (and therefore intercepted by
>   Selenium). You will see messages like
>   the following for each window as it is
>   opened:
>
> ```
> debug: window.open call intercepted; window ID (which you can
> ```
>
> use with selectWindow()) is
>   "myNewWindow"
>
> ```
> In some cases, Selenium will be unable to intercept a call to
> ```
>
> window.open (if the call occurs during
>   or before the "onLoad" event, for
>   example). (This is bug SEL-339.) In
>   those cases, you can force Selenium to
>   notice the open window's name by using
>   the Selenium openWindow command, using
>   an empty (blank) url, like this:
>   openWindow("", "myFunnyWindow").

selectWindow(windowID)

**selectPopup**

If it is a popup then do `selectPopUp | windowId` and then to go back to the main window do `selectWindow | null`

`selectPopUp(windowID)` Arguments:

- windowID - an identifier for the popup window, which can take on a number of different meanings

Simplifies the process of selecting a popup window (and does not offer functionality beyond what selectWindow() already provides).

- If windowID is either not specified, or specified as "null", the first non-top window is selected. The top window is the one that would be selected by selectWindow() without providing a windowID . This should not be used when more than one popup window is in play.
- Otherwise, the window will be looked up considering windowID as the following in order:

  1. The "name" of the window, as specified to window.open()
  2. A JavaScript variable which is a reference to a window
  3. The title of the window. This is the same ordered lookup performed by selectWindow

Comment: does the bug report here: http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-703 apply to what you've outlined above? i've been wrestling with selectWindow for hours now. driving me nuts.

Comment: Also, dont forget to place a ´waitForPopUp´ before the ´selectPopup´ to assure the popUp has finished loading before you try to select it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using Selenium Web Driver 2:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles.last);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the random window ID (generated by Selenium IDE) using ‘**storeAttribute**’ command. You just need to store the ID in a variable and then you can select the window using ‘**selectWindow**’ command.

Try using this:

```
<tr>
   <td>storeAttribute</td>
   <td>link=Help Center@target</td>
   <td>window_ID</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>selectWindow</td>
   <td>${window_ID}</td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this: would you prefer to just remove the `target="_blank"` attribute? For me this has been a solution:

```
getEval
this.page().findElement('link=Facebook').removeAttribute('target');
```

Staying within the same window has some advantages in Selenium IDE, seeing it doesn't support target blank.

Comment: looks like I downvoted this by accident -- the solution comes out rather elegant in a fashion wish I could improve to upvote

Comment: This actually is the fastest and most simple solution for most use cases. Also works on forms!