# Selenium IDE unable to open new windows from link when running through testcase

Tags: selenium, hyperlink, window, selenium-ide

So I'm writing tests for a web page, and one of the tests include clicking a link, which opens a new window, do some assertions in that window, and jump back.

To open links I'm using the technique described [here](http://nickbartlett.com/wordpress/selenium-ide-how-to-follow-links-in-opening-a-new-window/).

The weird thing is, when I go through the steps manually (just press all of them one after another) it works fine. But when I try to run the whole test, it either does nothing (no windows open) or it clicks another button (and not the link).

What can be the reason for it working when i do the steps manually, and not when Selenium IDE runs them for me?

Comment: Please refer following post for more details..

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859233/how-do-you-focus-on-new-windows-with-selenium-ide?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To open link, you can use

```
click  |  link=link name
selectWindow  |  windowname
```

And then perform operation on that window

Comment: This works when i go through the steps manully, but when I run the test case, it does not work. I should mention that even if i run through the steps manually, the "selectWindow"-command is never able to find the window. But the earlier tests I have made (pressing buttons and not links) can handle that.